# Can't boot latest raspios bullseye 64 bit lite image on 3B+

Tags: boot-issues

Tried using latestRaspberry Pi Imager (1.7.3), and direct downloads from site. When I choose 32 bit it works fine. When I choose the 64 bit version I get solid on red led and 7 flashes on green led. Screen shows rainbow.

I've tried on a PC and a Mac.
I've tried two different 3B+.
I've tried 3 different SD cards.
All with same result.
32 bit works fine, 64 bit does not work.

```
PS G:\> dir


Directory: G:\


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----        21/02/2023     03:53                overlays
-a----        06/01/2023     11:16          30170 bcm2710-rpi-2-b.dtb
-a----        06/01/2023     11:16          18693 COPYING.linux
-a----        06/01/2023     11:16           1594 LICENCE.broadcom
-a----        21/02/2023     04:08            145 issue.txt
-a----        06/01/2023     11:16          32533 bcm2710-rpi-3-b-plus.dtb
-a----        06/01/2023     11:16          31922 bcm2710-rpi-3-b.dtb
-a----        06/01/2023     11:16          30157 bcm2710-rpi-cm3.dtb
-a----        06/01/2023     11:16          31230 bcm2710-rpi-zero-2-w.dtb
-a----        06/01/2023     11:16          31230 bcm2710-rpi-zero-2.dtb
-a----        06/01/2023     11:16          52424 bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb
-a----        06/01/2023     11:16          52556 bcm2711-rpi-400.dtb
-a----        06/01/2023     11:16          53165 bcm2711-rpi-cm4.dtb
-a----        06/01/2023     11:16          50447 bcm2711-rpi-cm4s.dtb
-a----        06/01/2023     11:16          52476 bootcode.bin
-a----        21/02/2023     04:08            154 cmdline.txt
-a----        21/02/2023     03:53           2109 config.txt
-a----        06/01/2023     11:16           7265 fixup.dat
-a----        06/01/2023     11:16           5398 fixup4.dat
-a----        06/01/2023     11:16           3170 fixup4cd.dat
-a----        06/01/2023     11:16           8382 fixup4db.dat
-a----        06/01/2023     11:16           8386 fixup4x.dat
-a----        06/01/2023     11:16           3170 fixup_cd.dat
-a----        06/01/2023     11:16          10229 fixup_db.dat
-a----        06/01/2023     11:16          10229 fixup_x.dat
-a----        06/01/2023     11:16        8194604 kernel8.img
-a----        06/01/2023     11:16        2975104 start.elf
-a----        06/01/2023     11:16        2250848 start4.elf
-a----        06/01/2023     11:16         805436 start4cd.elf
-a----        06/01/2023     11:16        3747240 start4db.elf
-a----        06/01/2023     11:16        2998344 start4x.elf
-a----        06/01/2023     11:16         805436 start_cd.elf
-a----        06/01/2023     11:16        4819144 start_db.elf
-a----        06/01/2023     11:16        3721992 start_x.elf
```

Answer (score 0):

7 flashes: kernel.img not found - see [The Boot Problems Sticky](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=58151)

You have done something wrong; this should run on a Pi3B+ (although I have never bothered).
There is no advantage of 64 bit (except to run packages not available in 32 bit and it seems unlikely there are any which run on Lite).

Edit:
I just tried a 64 bit Raspberry Pi OS (not Lite) in my Pi3A and it works OK.

Comment: There is a kernel8.img, but no kernel.img.

Comment: 64 bit obviously only has a 64 bit kernel, but this should work on Pi3B+. Post the contents of /boot into your Question.

Comment: I've added the contents of the root. No sign of a /boot.

Comment: This looks OK - it has bcm2710-rpi-3-b.dtb Sorry I can't help as I never tried 64bit Lite, but according to the documentation it should work.

Comment: Appreciate the help so far.

Comment: `No sign of a /boot` that IS the `/boot` in linux :p

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that I was wrong in thinking that I had a 3B+, it was the B+ models that I was using. I posted to the rpi imager issues on github and this response explains very well:-

> Indeed. 7 short flashes indicates "kernel not found". The firmware knows that > kernel8.img, the only kernel binary in a 64-bit build, requires ARMv8 support > and therefore won't run on a B+.